# Form submissions not appending to CSV

Tags: php, html, csv

Someone has used my code and said that it worked for them, but for some reason on my mac, whenever I use my form it does not append to the CSV I have in my directory. It is an empty file named data.csv. Here is my code:

```html
<?php
$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subjects = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = clean_text($_POST["user_name"]);
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
        }
    if(empty($_POST["user_mail"])) {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
    } else {
        $email = clean_text($_POST["user_mail"]);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
        }
    }
    $subjects = clean_text($_POST["user_subjects"]);
    
    if($error == ''){
        $file_open = fopen("data.csv", 'a');
        $num_rows = count(file("data.csv"));
        $form_data = array(
            0 => $name,
            1 => $email,
            2 => $subjects
        );
        fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
        $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
        $name = '';
        $email = '';
        $subjects = '';
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            
            
            form {
                /* Just to center the form on the page */
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 400px;
                /* To see the outline of the form */
                padding: 1em;
                border: 1px solid #CCC;
                border-radius: 1em;
            }
            
            form div + div {
                margin-top: 1em;
            }
            
            label {
            /* To make sure that all labels have the same size and are properly aligned */
            display: inline-block;
            width: 120px;
            text-align: right;
            }
            
            input, textarea {
                /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
                By default, textareas have a monospace font */
                font: 1em sans-serif;

                /* To give the same size to all text fields */
                width: 250px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
            
            input:focus, textarea:focus {
            /* To give a little highlight on active elements */
            border-color: #1fb;
            }
            
            textarea {
            /* To properly align multiline text fields with their labels */
            vertical-align: top;
                
            /* To remove resizability feature */
            resize: none;

            /* To give enough room to type some text */
            height: 5em;
            }
            
            .button {
            /* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
            padding-left: 120px; /* same size as the label elements */
            }
            
            button {
            /* This extra margin represent roughly the same space as the space
            between the labels and their text fields */
            margin-left: .5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
        <form method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name" id="namelabel">(Optional) Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">(Optional) Requested Subjects:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_subjects" value="<?php echo $subjects; ?>"></textarea>
  </div>
    <div class="button">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In case you need it, here is a screenshot of my directory:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4gHT.jpg

Comment: Why does everyone use `htmlspecialchars()` when cleaning strings? That's not what it's for.

Comment: It should ONLY be used when displaying user-provided text on a web page, to prevent XSS.

Comment: Try using the full path to the CSV file. Also, you should use `fclose($file_open);` after you write to the file.

Comment: @Barmar even after entering the full path of the file it still did not work, any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for warnings.

Comment: Where should I put that line? I'm new to php. @Barmar

Comment: At the beginning, it enables full warnings for everything after it.

Comment: @Barmar nothing came up, does it work if you try to run the code?

Comment: Is the file writable by the webserver userID (probably www-data)? You should add error checking for `fopen()`.

Comment: I am launching it on my localhost, but how would I check for the error? I still have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in my code

Comment: You check for the error with `if (!$file_open) { die ("Could not open file"); }`

Comment: @Barmar Would something pop up on the site or in terminal? Neither happened, so I'm assuming there's no error

Comment: If you use that line after the `fopen()` line, you should see the "Could not open file" message on the site. If you don't see that, then the file is opening successfully and it should append to the file.

Comment: If you're not seeing the added lines, are you sure you're looking for the file in the correct folder?